# In AWS, i had a RDS with active connections. I am able to retrieve no of active connections but not sure how to get those active details using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-python

In AWS, i had a RDS with active connections. I am able to retrieve no of active connections but not sure how to get those active details using python.

If i find the RDS has active db connections, then i should get details of it like connection id/connection IP

I am able to fetch the number of active DB connections. Now i am trying to find a way to retrieve details of those active connections. Not sure how can i achieve my requirement. I use python script following boto3 documentation.

Comment: for that, you would have to connect to your DB and run the query `SHOW processlist`

Comment: @Caldazar, I have to get those active connection details through my python script. How to incorporate it to script so that i get those details after my script execution.